# Am I doing something wrong here?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

I'm sorry if my question is very vague as i'm very very very new to coding and asking coding questions but i hope someone understands my problem as this is very frustrating because an error message doesn't appear but i don't know what im doing wrong.

So for context, i have a array number shuffler.

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

function shuffle(o) {
  for (let j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
  return o;
};
let random = shuffle(numbers);
```

im trying to make a random number generator without repetition and im going to use those numbers to generate random images correlating to the number. So i set the first image to the first index of random

```
let setImgUrl = "img" + random[0] + ".jpg";
```

and now i want to make a button that shifts it to random[1] as a way to switch to the next random image.

```
let calcNewImg;
if (random[0]) {
  calcNewImg = random[1]
} else if (random[1]) {
  calcNewImg = random[2]
}
```

it'll keep repeating to random[9] (which is the last index) and the image appears like this

```
Img.setAttribute("src", "img/img" + calcNewImg + ".jpg");
```

when i click the button to switch to the next image, it works once and doesnt work the any other time with no error message. Hope i gave enough info that someone can understand, please feel free to ask for more info if it is needed. i really appreciate this help.

Comment: _"Hope i gave enough info that someone can understand..."_ - It's a good start but please add a [mcve] (preferable as [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)) that shows the actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is an infinite loop to generate the image Ids something like this

```js
button=document.getElementById("button")
  showimg=document.getElementById("showimg")

  button.addEventListener("click",getimg)

let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
function shuffle(o) {
 for(let j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
 return o;
};
let random = shuffle(numbers);
var i=0
function getimg(){
    calcNewImg = random[i]
   i++
  if(i>=random.length){
   i=0
 }
   
   showimg.textContent= "img/img" + calcNewImg + ".jpg"

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="showimg">###</div>
 <br>
  <button id="button">generate</button>

</body>
</html>
```